# Pop to previous UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have two UINavigationControllers like this:

```
LoginNavigationController -> LoginView
HomeNavigationController -> HomeView -> ...
```

From LoginView I navigate to HomeView like this:

```
[self presentViewController:HomeNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Now when app goes to background I need to go to LoginView. What is the right way to do this? Will redirecting with presentViewController cause any memory issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code in LoginView -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodEnterBGMode) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

}

- (void)methodEnterBGMode
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your`LoginViewController` is the root view controller in the hierarchy, perhaps you could call`popToRootViewController` on the`rootViewController` in your app delegate (in`applicationWillEnterForeground` or something)

Answer (score 0):

You can use view controllers `popToRootViewController`. first, you need to find the previous controller you want to go to,
On your HomeNavigationController,

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
        if([controller isKindOfClass:[LoginNavigationController  class]]){

            [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
            break;
        }
    }
```

execute this code when app goes to background and then to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Presenting is probably not what you want, since it is presenting yet another view controller instead of the one already loaded. I would go with popping to the root view controller.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `AppDelegate`'s `applicationDidEnterBackground` method change the root view controller of window.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

    // Change the rootViewController of your window.. 
}
```